# Custom filter with Django Filters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filters

I am trying to write my own custom filter class as follows using `django_filters`:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class FooFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Model 
        fields = ['custom_field',]


class Foo():
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = FooFilter
```

In models, as I do not have the field `custom_field`, it will give the error: `TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: custom_field`

Question: Is it possible to define my own custom query that is a non-model field name using Django Filterset?

Comment: What is `custom_field` in your `Model`?

Comment: It is just an arbitrary name. I want to use this 'custom name' as a query parameter when I make a request but this name is not a field in my models.

Comment: well if it is not a field in your model, it makes no sense to use it. If you want to make an extra filter field, you will need to define such field first and implement a method that will filter the queryset.

Comment: Maybe you should look at `method` argument [django filter doc](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=method#method) and add`custom_field`  above `class meta`.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense. But can I define this and implement this method with a custom queryset in FooFilter class? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @ludel Thank you. I will try and look through the documentation again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define an arbitrary function that will filter the queryset further. For example:

```
class MyFilterSet(FilterSet):
    custom_field = CharFilter(method='filter_not_empty')

    def filter_custom_field(queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(… some filtering …)

    class Meta:
        model = Model
        fields = ['custom_field']
```

Here we thus define a `CharFilter` for `custom_field` that thus will parse a string. With `method='filter_not_empty', we refer to the method that will be called.

This method is called with a `queryset` that needs to be filtered, `name` is the name of the filter field (here it is `custom_field`, but you can, if you want, use the same method for *multiple* filter set fields), and the value.

The method should return a `QuerySet` that is filtered down with `… some filtering …`

Comment: How can i add or condition in queryset.filter? i find out that, for example, this doesn't work: `queryset.filter(name__icontains=value, sku__iexact=value)`
neither this: `queryset.filter(Product(name__icontains)=value | Product(sku__iexact=value))`

Comment: @MicheleCandura: please ask a new question and include the relevant models.

Comment: ok thank you for the suggestion, here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71798874/13712068