# Django - How to add "or" condition to queryset.filter in custom filter

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

I want to make a search filter which searches in multiple fields with multiple conditions, using only one search field. I have this filters.py file:

```py
import django_filters
from .models import Product


class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='search_filter', label='Cerca')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['q']

    def search_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(name__icontains=value, sku__iexact=value)
```

But `return queryset.filter(name__icontains=value, sku__iexact=value)` doesn't work, neither `return queryset.filter(Product(name__icontains=value) | Product(sku__iexact=value))`
How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share the `Product` model. What do you mean with "doesn't work"...

Comment: The product model has name and sku fields, if it's what you are looking for.
When i try the first solution on the bottom of my post it works as a "and" condition, when i try the second i get the error: Product() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name__icontains'
Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can filter with [**`Q`** objects <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q):

```
import django_filters
from django.db.models import Q
from .models import Product

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='search_filter', label='Cerca')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['q']

    def search_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(Q(name__icontains=value) | Q(sku__iexact=value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without [**Q()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q), you can also run **`OR` operater** as shown below:

```py
import django_filters
from .models import Product

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    q = django_filters.CharFilter(method='search_filter', label='Cerca')

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['q']

    def search_filter(self, queryset, name, value): # Here
        return queryset.filter(name__icontains=value) | \
               queryset.filter(sku__iexact=value)
```